# How to create empty string using for loop PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm trying to create for loop giving strings empty value. How I can do it?

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++) {

    $b2_ch_v = ${'b2_g_v_'.$i}['id'];
    $$b2_ch_v = '';

}

/*
result should be:
$b2_g_v_1['id'] = '';
$b2_g_v_2['id'] = '';
[...]
$b2_g_v_24['id'] = '';
*/
```

Comment: What about `$$b2_ch_v = ['id' => ''];` ? Side note, arrays are probably easier to handle than variable variables

Comment: This seems a lot like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Why don't you tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: To whoever voted to close due to being unclear: I find this question incredibly clear - there is an example attempt with code and the expected result...

Answer (score 3):

Don't use variables named like `$x1`, `$x2`, `$x3`. You almost always want to use arrays instead. In this case, you can use an indexed array of associative arrays. This is sometimes also called a two-dimensional array.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 24; $i++) {
    $b2_ch_v[$i] = ['id' => ''];
}
```

Then your first element becomes:

```
$b2_ch_v[0]
```

And its named elements can be referred to via:

```
$b2_ch_v[0]['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `$b2_ch_v` to the current contents of the `id` element of the array, not a reference to the array element. You need to refer to the array index in the assignment.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++) {
    $b2_ch_v = 'b2_g_v_'.$i;
    ${$b2_ch_v}['id'] = '';
}

var_dump($b2_g_v_1); // => array(1) { ["id"]=> string(0) "" }
```

You don't actually need the variable, you can do the calculation in the assignment:

```
${'b2_g_v_'.$i}['id'] = '';
```

But it's best to avoid variable variables in the first place, and use arrays instead as in the other answer.